# RTE AEM6.2 By default Addition of p tag

Tags: aem

I tried removing the p tag from RTE of AEM(6.2) by adding the property removeSingleParagraphContainer :true  in rte text node.It removes the p tag from first paragraph but as soon as we enter the next paragarph  the p tag gets added.It seems the component needed to be customized from out of box.
Is there any other way can we achieve this.
The functionality which I require is that no tag should get added until users selects a specific formatter tag from paraformat.

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this issue once upon a time. As far as I know there is no way to do it with configuration. You'll need custom code to get rid of these `<p>`'s.

One thing I can advise is that it's far easier to do it from within your code once already reading the property from JCR - then tweaking the aem component not to add it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour of RTE OOTB. removeSingleParagraphContainer is for backward compatibility and not the behaviour you are expecting.

By default, pressing Enter will add a **`<p>`** tag but if you press **Shift+Enter** (at least on Mac, not sure on Windows) you will get a **`<br>`** tag which is probably what you are expecting.

The only way to change the behaviour is to overlay the RTE control.